# Can't assert toBeCalled with fireEvent.submit

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

Can't get expect `onSubmit` to `toBeCalled` to pass by any mean. Algo having similar problems with `onClick` in a different component.

**Login.js**

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {

        sanctumApi
            .get("sanctum/csrf-cookie")
            .then(() => {
                // do more stuff
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err, "cookie");
            });
    };
```

**Form in Login.js**

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail">
    <Form.Label>Correo electrónico</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control
      type="email"
      placeholder="Ingresa tu correo electrónico"
      name="email"
      value={email}
      onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      required
    />

  </Form.Group>

  <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword">
    <Form.Label>Contraseña</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control
      type="password"
      placeholder="Ingresa tu contraseña"
      name="password"
      value={password}
      onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
      required
    />
  </Form.Group>
  <Form.Group controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
    <Form.Check
      type="checkbox"
      label="Recordar usuario"
      defaultChecked={rememberMe}
      onChange={() => setRememberMe(!rememberMe)}
    />
  </Form.Group>
  <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
    Iniciar sesión
  </Button>
  <Link to="/register">
    // register
  </Link>
  <br />
  <Link to="/forgot-password">
    <Button variant="link" className="mt-2">
      //
    </Button>
  </Link>
  <br />
  <Link to="/">
    <Button variant="outline-secondary" className="mt-2">
      //back
    </Button>
  </Link>
</Form>;
```

**Login.test.js**

```
it("submit with login btn", async () => {
  //mock submit
  const handleSubmit = jest.fn();
  render(
    <HashRouter>
      <Login loggedIn={false} onSubmit={handleSubmit} />
    </HashRouter>
  );

  // fill email input
  const emailInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText(
    /Ingresa tu correo electrónico/i
  );
  fireEvent.change(emailInput, {
    target: { value: "user@example.com" },
  });
  // fill password input
  const pwInput = screen.getByPlaceholderText(/Ingresa tu contraseña/i);
  fireEvent.change(pwInput, { target: { value: "123456" } });

  const loginBtn = screen.getByRole("button", {
    name: /Iniciar sesión/i,
  });

  // assert elements
  expect(emailInput.value).toBe("user@example.com");
  expect(pwInput.value).toBe("123456");
  expect(loginBtn).toBeInTheDocument();

  fireEvent.submit(loginBtn);

  await waitFor(() => expect(handleSubmit).toBeCalled());
});
```

The output from console:

```
      53 |             })
      54 |             .catch((err) => {
    > 55 |                 console.error(err, "cookie");
         |                         ^
      56 |             });
      57 |     };
      58 |

      at console.error (node_modules/@testing-library/react/dist/act-compat.js:53:34)
      at resources/js/components/auth/Login.js:55:25

  ● Login View › submit with login btn

    expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0
```

This output -the `.catch` mainly- makes me think that the `submit` is fired, yet I can't assert this.

According to docs(https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/#using-jest-function-mocks):

The function must be `mocked` via `jest.fn()` and then passed as `onSubmit` prop into the `Component` rendered via `render` method. Then the event gets fired using `fireEvent.submit(el)` to finally be asserted with `expect - toHaveBeenCalled` or similar.

What's wrong here?

Thank ya'll,

Fernando

Comment: Could you please post `Login` component, or at least all the parts that use `onSubmit` prop ?

Comment: sure, it's updated

Comment: It appears that in your source code the `handleSubmit` function is declared inside your `Login` component, passing an `onSubmit` mock via props in your test will have no effect to mock it. Instead, mock the `sanctumApi` dependency and test that.

Comment: Yeah I get you.  That would work only if `onSubmit` was coming as a prop from the parent component. So actually passing `onSubmit` as prop to the `render` is not helping at all.